# Magento translations dont work

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I have a pretty weird problem. I see that some parts of my Magento translations are not working. I have the .csv translation files under right folder, and I have translated all fields for my language.

I see that 90% of the store is translated, but some parts just don't work. In example most of the checkout proces is translated, but sentance "Coupon is invalid" does not take affect.

Has anyone had this problem before? Can someone help?

Thanks

Comment: Are you adding new translations, rather than amending old ones? If you simple add new rows to the file it will not get translated for you...

Answer (score 1):

A couple things with this... First off, inline translation is known to have issues with translating 100% of things. Make sure as well that there does not already exist an inline translation for what you are trying to translate with your CSV. Make sure to refresh the translation cache in `Configuration > Cache Management` in the admin backend (and subsequently, if you're using block caching or full page caching, refresh that as well.)

Answer (score 0):

Translation uses following :
1. Module name and language to decide which .csv file and folder to be used.

1. translation might come from a cache block or a FPC as commented in other post.
2. Transalation string is matched with string in csv and any difference in string might result in values not being displayed.

Suggested solution :
Make sure which block or .phtml is that string being generated and check its module xml file for something like this
  as this tells Magento which module transalation file to be used.

also check for translate node within a module xml file.Something similar to this

```
<translate>
            <modules>
                <Phoenix_Moneybookers>
                    <files>
                        <default>Phoenix_Moneybookers.csv</default>
                    </files>
                </Phoenix_Moneybookers>
            </modules>
</translate>
```